# `ERROR Error: Cannot match any routes.` - angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

Here is my router in ts file:

```
{
        path: 'cpServices',
        component: CpServiceComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'contentPlaceholder',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'contentPlaceholder',
                data: { showNavi: true },
                component: ShellContentPlaceholderComponent,

                children : [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentViewPlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentViewPlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'create',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'edit',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentEditPlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'update',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentUpdatePlaceholderComponent,
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

when the browser holds the path as `http://localhost:4200/#/cpServices/contentPlaceholder` I am start to type `view` the the current path. so the path updated as `http://localhost:4200/#/cpServices/contentPlaceholder/view` - now I am expecting the view page. but instead I am getting an error as:

`ERROR Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cpServices/contentPlaceHolder/view'` - what is the issue here? the same works fine with Firefox. but chrome not working.

Even though `Firefox` load the page, the `css1 not loading it takes all default styles unless i refresh the same page.

what is causing here? how to solve it?

any one help me?

**UPDATE**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'pfServices', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'setupConfig', loadChildren: () => import('./../setup-config/setup-config.module').then(m => m.SetupConfigModule) },
    { path: 'pfServices', loadChildren: () => import('./../pf-services/pf-services.module').then(m => m.PfServicesModule) }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', useHash: false})
    ],
    // providers: [AuthenticationGuard],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutesModule { }
```

Comment: What is the "#" on the URL for? >>> http://localhost:4200/#/cpServices/contentPlaceholder

Comment: that's come as default, I am not set anything

Comment: In case if I copy `http://localhost:4200/#/cpServices/contentPlaceholder/view` and paste it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I advise you not to use hash in routing. Just disable it in the router config

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})
```

Comment: Please see my update in my quesiton, just adding this not working.. I am using angular 8. need add anything else?